# Query field as string?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'd like to query a model for a specific field I've got as a string.

**Demo:**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    someones_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    anothers_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# python shell:
>> Foo.objects.get(pk=1).someones_name
u'Cpt. Hook'
>> Foo.objects.get(pk=1).anothers_name
u'Peter Pan'
```

Now - I got in a variable the name of the field `someones_name`

```
>> field_name = 'someones_name'
```

So, how do I perform the almost same query against the Foo-Model with that field_name-variable? If indeed such a thing is possible?

---

**Edit**

I'm not looking to query with that field_name. I want the exact value of the field given in field_name. I know that I could do something like this

```
query = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
query.someones_name
query.anothers_name
```

All I need is to get this one specific field I dynamicaly receive from `._meta.fields` (from another model) as a string.

In RAW-SQL something like: `'SELECT %s FROM foo where pk = 1' % field_name`

Comment: Do you want to pass a string as a field for lookup?

Comment: Yes, exactly - that's what I'm looking for. **edit** no - sorry. mixed it up. I'm looking to get exact the value of one field within the model

Comment: This is covered in the documentation in excruciating detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects. Always, always, always read the docs before asking a question here. Asking on StackOverflow should be your last resort, not your first.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I know how to query - maybe my updated question could clarify some misunderstandings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
field_name = 'someones_name'
Foo.objects.get(**{field_name: 'Cpt. Hook'})
```

It is equal to:

```
Foo.objects.get(someones_name='Cpt. Hook')
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
field_name = 'someones_name'
obj = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
getattr(obj, field_name)
```

Equal to:

```
Foo.objects.get(pk=1).someones_name
```

Comment: @init3: Just FYI, they're called "attributes" (hence `getattr`), not "query fields". When you've already gotten an object, which is an instance of a class, that instance has attributes. Technically even methods are still considered attibutes and can be looked up the same way with `getattr`.